# How does mail2web.com work?

Tags: email

Can you please explain working concept of mail2web.com ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works quite similar as Outlook or Thunderbird.

It will login on the e-mail server you provide, but instead of showing it in a program on your desktop it will show it in the browser window.

If the e-mail provider doesn't have a webmail interface (quite unlikely these days) you can use solutions like this on the go. But it does mean you are giving away the login details to someone you don't actually know, who knows what they do with it.

Comment: +1 for "you are giving your login data to a random stranger"

Answer (score 1):

It's a website which logs into a POP3 or iMAP mail server and displays the emails which are on the mail server so that you can access them from any web browser.  This is handy if you have an email hosting company that doesn't include webmail, or the webmail doesn't work on your mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail from Google also have great integration with other POP3 servers, but also got many benefits like, addons for mozila or IE so it can work faster a great amount of space and also mobile version and others